# Atom - unset window:close keybinding/keymap

Tags: macos, atom-editor

I'm trying to remove this line in keybindings:

```
shift-cmd-W window:close    Core    body
```

Tried to change the keymap.cson but to no avail:

```
'body':
  'shift-cmd-W': 'unset!'
```

I'm trying to stop my whole editor closing when I accidentally hit `cmd-shift-W`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atom may still be running `'ctrl-shift-W'`, try:

```
`'body':
  'shift-cmd-W': 'unset!'
  'ctrl-shift-W': 'unset!'
```